# inserting an item into a deque

Tags: java, queue, deque

Focusing specifically on the insertFront() method in main, how do I go about creating an item that holds the values of num and price.  Further more should it hold the values of num and price or userinNum and userinPrice?

```
theQueue.insertFront(//ITEM???);
```

Main method MyDequeApp:

```
import java.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MyDequeApp {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String userinNum;
    double userinPrice;

    Item item1= new Item();

    Scanner scan1=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the number of elements in the que");
    int queElm=scan1.nextInt();

    MyDeque theQueue=new MyDeque(queElm);

    System.out.println("1. Insert to front");
    System.out.println("2. Insert to rear");
    System.out.println("3. Remove from front");
    System.out.println("4. Remove from rear");
    System.out.println("5. Peek front");
    System.out.println("6. Peek rear");
    System.out.println("7. Display que");
    System.out.println("8. Quit");

    int queOp=scan1.nextInt();

    switch(queOp)
    {
        //1. Insert to front
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Enter an item #");
            userinNum=scan1.nextLine();
            item1.setNum(userinNum);
            System.out.println("Enter a price");
            userinPrice=scan1.nextDouble();
            item1.setPrice(userinPrice);
            System.out.println(item1.toString());
            theQueue.insertFront();
                break;

        case 5:
            theQueue.peekFront();
                break;

        default:
            break;


    }



}

}
```

Class Item:

```
public class Item {

double price;
String num;

//set/get method
public void setPrice(double userinPrice)
{
    price=userinPrice;
}

public double getPrice()
{
    return price;
}


public void setNum(String userinNum)
{
    num=userinNum;
}

public String getNum()
{
    return num;
}

//toString()
public String toString()
{
    return "Item number: "+num+"\n"+"Price: $"+price;
}

}
```

Insert method from class MyDeque:

```
    public void insertFront(Item x)
    {
    if(front==maxSize)
        front=0;
    queArray[front++]=x;
    nItems++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would insert the entire `Item` in the queue, which would have both the price and num set.

To create an Item just create and instance ('new it up'), then set the num and price:

```
Item newItem = new Item();
newItem.setPrice(someDoubleValue);
newItem.setNum(someStringValue);

theQueue.insertFront(newItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a constructor for `Item` that accepts the values of `userinNum` and `userinPrice` and invoke it after retrieving the user's inputs.

```
public Item(String num, double price){
    this.num = num;
    this.price = price;
}
```

By using a constructor like this, you can get the user's inputs and store them in variables, and then once you have the input you can invoke it and pass it those variables:

```
item1 = new Item(userinNum, userinPrice);
```

Then you can just add `item1` to your dequeue. This combines the `setNum()` and `setPrice()` steps into one line.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I've misunderstood your question here

> Further more should it hold the values of num and price or userinNum
>   and userinPrice?

`userinNum` and `userinPrice` are just variables you're using to hold the input given to you by the user. `num` and `price` just attributes of the `Item` class, to which you are assigning the values the user gave you.

To add your item to the queue, change the line `theQueue.insertFront();` to  `theQueue.insertFront(item1);`.